# Procedure creating multithreads

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have an issue regarding oracle procedure in packages. Most of the procedure are inserts of this type. I was told it was creating around 30 threads with my user, when I only had one open session. What could be the problem? Is it engine related or my fault? Is there any way I can reduce the number of threads to reduce db lag?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO EST_PARDEPAR_CIVIL
select 0 status, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by e.ID_EXPEDIENTE order by             
a.FECHA_ACTUACION,a.ID_ACTUACION_EXP) orden,
e.ID_EXPEDIENTE,o.ID_OFICINA,o2.ID_OFICINA ID_JUZGADO,  a.FECHA_ACTUACION, 
o.DESCRIPCION DESCRIPCION_OFICINA, o2.DESCRIPCION DESCRIPCION_JUZGADO
, ee.ID_ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE, a.ID_ACTUACION_EXP,
CASE WHEN ee.CODIGO_ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE in (''PDO'',''PAR'') THEN         
''PARALIZADO'' ELSE ''DESPARALIZADO'' END TIPO_ESTADO, ' || to_char(camara) 
|| '
from ACTUACION_EXP a 
JOIN EXPEDIENTE e on e.ID_EXPEDIENTE = a.ID_EXPEDIENTE
JOIN EST_EXPEDIENTES_CIVIL ie on ie.ID_EXPEDIENTE = e.ID_EXPEDIENTE
JOIN ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE ee on ee.ID_ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE = 
a.ID_ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE and ee.status != -1 and ee.genera_estado_procesal = 1
JOIN OFICINA o on o.ID_OFICINA = a.ID_OFICINA
JOIN OFICINA o2 on o2.ID_OFICINA = nvl(o.ID_OFICINA_SUPERIOR, o.ID_OFICINA)
where ee.CODIGO_ESTADO_EXPEDIENTE in 
(''PDO'',''PAR'',''SAC'',''DPA'',''DES'')
and o.ID_camara = ' || to_char(camara);

commit;
```

Comment: Probably the database server decided to run the `select` part or even the `insert` part with parallel execution. But that would only happen if Oracle was configured to automatically use parallel execution of statements. If that is the case the DBA should configure it to use less resources. You could try to use the `NO_PARALLEL` hint for the SELECT and the INSERT to avoid that.

Comment: Apparently the SELECT is the problem, so how do I use hints while on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? I'm getting errors while trying

Comment: `select /* no_parallel */ ...` should do it: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF00219

Comment: It doesn't work with execute immediate: SQL command not properly ended. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO EST_EXPEDIENTES_CIVIL NOPARALLEL (ID_EXPEDIENTE,ID_CAMARA)
         SELECT /* no_parallel */ gives an error

Comment: Of course it does.

Comment: It gets an error, I edited the message above :(